# How to invoke ess (R in emacs) on Windows?

Tags: emacs, ess

`ESS` is a fantistic package, and it works great on linux. When I run *emacs + ess + R* on Windows, the usual way `M-x R` failed to start R. It says: "No Match".

I can start it with an extra step:

1. `M-x ess-smart-equals` insert an equal sign in the scratch buffer.
2. `M-x R`, this time, it works.

I guess I need to active it somewhere, but I don't know how.

I also tried to open an `.R` file, place the cursor on a line of R code, and hit `ctrl-enter` to run it. Again, it doesn't work.

```
Windows 7 64-bit
GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2015-05-17 on KAEL
ess-version: 15.09-devel [elpa: 20150708.1130] (loaded from c:/Users/Nick/.emacs.d/elpa/ess-20150708.1130/)
```

Is there any configuration I need to do here?

Comment: Can you show what you have in your .emacs to load ESS, or is it all done by MELPA?  Also, you could try http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/ if you want an Emacs for windows which should work with ESS "out of the box".

Comment: @StephenEglen Thank you for pointing me the `Vincent Goulet` Windows port. This problem was solved by reinstall and update several packages. Maybe there's a certain package which has some minor difference between Linux and Windows platform. May I answer my own question?